# ¿Hay alguna funcion para obtener datos de mi store en EXTJS?

Tags: javascript, variables, extjs

buenas tardes tengo un dilema es sobre como puedo obtener datos de mi store y guardarlos en variables esto para posibles validaciones ,en este caso tengo mi store del que quiero obtener un dato que es la jornada para guardar en  una variable y así validar, la cosa es que no se como guardar en una variable variable , ya esta mis store y los datos si se muestran en una tabla .
anexo codigo de mis store :

```
   autoLoad: true,
proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy(
    {
        url: 'controladorDetalle.php?task=getdetalle&start=0&limit=50',
    }),
reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
    root: 'rows',
    totalProperty: 'total',
    id: 'id'
},
    [
        { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'id_h_laboral', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'id_h_laboral2', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'horario', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'dia', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'hora_inicial', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'hora_final', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'hora_inicial2', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'hora_final2', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'jornada', type: 'string' }


    ]),
baseParams: { start: 0, limit: 50 },
```

});`

Answer (score 0):

Hay muchas funciones: `store.getRecords()`, `store.find()`, `store.findBy`, `store.findExact()`, `store.findRecord()`. ¿En dónde quieres hacer las validaciones? Para ello puedes utilizar `validate` en cada columna de una grid o mostrarlas diferente utilizando `convert` en el modelo o `renderer` en la grid.